# cant read data from QTcpSocket

Tags: qt, qtcpsocket

I use QTcpSocket to open a connection and receive the data. But I'm having issues reading data from then socket.

// header file

```
    class PeerWireClient : public QTcpSocket
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:

    PeerWireClient(QObject *parent = 0);

private slots:
    void readFromSocket();

private:

    qint64 socketBytesAvailable() const { return QTcpSocket::bytesAvailable(); }
    // Data waiting to be read/written
    QByteArray incomingBuf;
    QByteArray outgoingBuf;
};
```

// cpp file

```
PeerWireClient::PeerWireClient(QObject *parent) :
    QTcpSocket(parent)
{
    connect(this, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readFromSocket()));
}

void PeerWireClient::readFromSocket(void)
{
    qint64 oldsize, size;
    qint64 readbytes = 0;

    oldsize = incomingBuf.size();
    size = socketBytesAvailable();
    if (size > 0) {
        incomingBuf.resize(oldsize + size);
        readbytes = read((incomingBuf.data()+oldsize), size);
        qDebug("%ld", readbytes); // 
        qDebug("data: %s", incomingBuf.constData());
    }
}
```

If I try to send 281 bytes data from the other side then 
the read function return 281 bytes but the is no data in buffer.

```
Debug: 
281

data:
```

I dont know what I am doing wrong. How can I make this work?

Comment: Please show how you send the data, and what data you are sending. If the first byte of that data is `\0`, you might actually not have a problem at all...

Comment: printing binary data using qDebug() isn't a good idea, try printing it as hex, using qDebug( ...., incomingBuf.toHex().constData());

Comment: i used netcat to send the data from a file. i've extended my debug. I used qDebug to see the incomingBuf.size vor and after the read. And i see vor the read the size is 281 and after is 0. :(

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, the value is right but the actual string received is rarely the right one sometimes there are some things in it sometimes not.